# forastero vs. extranjero

Tags: vocabulario, significado-en-contexto

A translation of the bible has “No aceptes como rey a ningún forastero ni extranjero.”

I thought this seemed redundant, and dictionaries I consulted seemed to confirm that.

What is the difference (if any)?

(For what it's worth, the original Hebrew also seemed redundant.  Perhaps the translators just wanted to mirror that.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Extranjero* always means a person from a different nation, foreign to ours, with a different government, language, customs, and uses. Not just people are *extranjero*, but also things, such as fashions and objects.

> *Forastero* implies nationality, closeness, similarity in essentials, and only slight and accidental differences.

<sub>*Source [wikilengua](https://www.wikilengua.org/index.php/forastero#:%7E:text=La%20diferencia%20que%20en%20espa%C3%B1ol,las%20modas%20y%20los%20objetos.)*</sub>

A Portuguese in NY is *extranjero* while a Texan in NY is a *forastero*

Comment: Actually, I don't know if it's correct, how do you call a person from Texas in English? (*tejano* or *texano* in Spanish)

Comment: @Danielillo Parte de la broma es que un texan en NYC a veces esté más cerca ser extranjero que forastero.  Y también google dice extranjero=foreigner, y forastero=outsider.

Comment: Ah, pues no lo sabía. Hago bromas sin entenderlas ni conocerlas 

Answer (score 0):

Con todo el respeto, pienso que los conceptos que actualmente tenemos sobre "**extranjero y forastero**" no deben de ser aplicados cuando hablamos de un texto bíblico. Por tanto utilizarlos bajo definiciones modernas, no es lo más sensato, pues se pierden los detalles de la interpretación arcaica.

> With all due respect, I think that the concepts we currently have
> about "**extranjero y forastero**" should not be applied when we talk
> about a biblical text. Therefore, using them under modern definitions
> is not the most sensible, since the details of the archaic
> interpretation are lost.

Ambas palabras "**extranjero y forastero**", tienen un origen más inmediato, así la palabra "Extranjero del francés antiguo "estrangier", aparece en español como "estrangero" y se encuentra documentada desde 1293. La palabra "Forastero", más antigua, en última instancia procedente del latín "foras" (lugar a donde), "fuera", utilizado en el español antiguo tanto como extranjero, forastero o venedizo (*Persona que va sin empleo u oficio a establecerse en un país o en un pueblo. Extranjero, forastero. Hoy en día evolucionada a advenedizo*).

> Both words "**extranjero y forastero**" have a more immediate origin, thus
> the word "Extranjero" from the Old French "estrangier" appears in
> Spanish as "estrangero" and is documented since 1293. The word
> "Forastero", older, in Ultimately from the Latin "foras" (place
> where), "outside" (fuera), used in old Spanish as foreigner, foreigner
> or venedizo (*Person who goes without a job or trade to settle in a
> country or a town. Foreigner (Extranjero), outsider (Forastero). Today
> evolved to advenedizo*).

> **Deuteronomio 17:15 NVI**
>
> asegúrate de nombrar como rey a uno de tu mismo pueblo,  uno que el
>
> SEÑOR tu Dios elija.  **No aceptes como rey a ningún forastero ni**
>
> **extranjero.**

En la época antigua los conceptos de país, nación, fronteras o tierra eran muy distintos a los actuales ya que distintos pueblos podían vivir en la misma tierra, pertenecer a diferentes clanes y tribus, estar incluso bajo la autoridad de un mismo rey y aún así estar encontrados luchando entre ellos, por tanto la complejidad no es banal.

> In ancient times, the concepts of country, nation, borders or land were very
> different from the current ones since different peoples could live on
> the same land, belong to different clans and tribes, even be under the
> authority of the same king and still be found. fighting among
> themselves, therefore the complexity is not trivial.

Aunque a lo largo de la Biblia encontramos varios contextos e interpretaciones distintas, a veces confundiendo los términos "extranjero y forastero" y otras separándolos,

> Although throughout the Bible we find several different contexts and
> interpretations, sometimes confusing the terms "foreigner and
> stranger" and others separating them,
>
> **Génesis 23:4-6**
>
> Extranjero y forastero (algunas traducciones lo interpretan como
> peregrino) soy entre vosotros; dadme propiedad para sepultura entre
> vosotros, y sepultaré mi muerta de delante de mí.

en términos generales, cuando la Biblia dice "**que el Rey no debe de ser "extranjero"**", está indicando principalmente dos cosas.

> In general terms, when the Bible says"**que el Rey no debe de ser
> "extranjero"**", it is mainly indicating two things.

**La primera**, que en el trono no debe colocarse a una persona que tenga intereses distintos a los del pueblo judío, y **la segunda**, que el rey no debe regirse por preceptos religiosos distintos a los de su Dios, en este caso, este Dios Hebreo del antiguo testamento.

> **The first**, that a person who has interests other than those of the
> Jewish people should not be placed on the throne, and **the second**, that
> the king should not be governed by religious precepts other than those
> of his God, in this case, this Hebrew God. of the old testament.

Cuando dice "**que el Rey no debe de ser "forastero"**" la biblia esta aludiendo a que el Rey no debe de ser elegido de entre aquellos que están de paso o no sean residentes conocidos, con "conocido" no solo se refiere a la persona elegida, sino a las distintas generaciones de la familia que han habitado en el lugar a lo largo del tiempo.

> When it says "**que el Rey no debe de ser "forastero"**" the bible
> means that the King should not be chosen from among those who are
> passing through or are not known residents, with "known" (conocido) not only It
> refers to the chosen person, but to the different generations of the
> family that have lived in the place over time.

Por tanto, **No aceptes como rey a ningún forastero ni extranjero.** significa que no se debe aceptar a una persona que no pertenezca al "Pueblo de Dios", es decir, al "**Pueblo elegido**", que según ellos es el pueblo Hebreo y por tanto esa persona debe de estar dentro de aquellos que conforman las "**Doce Tribus de Israel**", pues todo aquel que no se rija por la ley de Dios, en uno u en otro sentido, es un ser extraño, ajeno y no reconocido ante los "**Hijos de Israel**". Así el rey aceptado debe de ser entre aquellos que son considerados "**Hijos de Israel**" (B'nai Yisrael))

> Therefore, **No aceptes como rey a ningún forastero ni extranjero.**
> means that you should not accept a person who does not belong to the
> "**People of God**", that is, the "**Chosen People**", which according to > them
> is the Hebrew people and therefore that person must be within those
> that make up the "**Twelve Tribes of Israel**", because everyone who is
> not governed by the law of God, in one way or another, is a strange,
> alien and unacknowledged before the  "**Sons of Israel**" (Hijos de
> Israel). Thus the accepted king must be among those who are considered
> " **Sons of Israel**" (B'nai Yisrael, Hijos de Israel)).

[image]

*Joshua's allotment of land to the Israelite tribes according to Joshua 13–19*

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twelve_Tribes_of_Israel

Comment: It is true that definitions have changed.  But translators of many recent versions have been willing to vary somewhat from a literal meaning to get the intended meaning across to today's readers.  (In some cases, what the translators think is the intended meaning.)  Anyway, the point of the question was not hermeneutics but usage.

Comment: For what it's worth, the ancient Greek literally translates to "stranger who is not your relative."

Comment: I'm not sure whether I was referring to the Septuagint (Greek) or meant to say Hebrew (the original)